# Why can hr create an Oracle DB session though not using PWFILE?

Tags: oracle, authentication

I have created a database. HR schema has been enabled.

`connect / as sysdba` is known as operating system authentication.

`connect hr/password` is not operating system authentication right ? If yes, I guess that authentication is possible only with the oracle password file located at `ORACLE_HOME/database` for Windows.

I have queried `V$PWFILE_USERS` but it only showed me `sys`... Other users (such as hr, system, ...) are not in that view and I guess not in the password file.

Why ? What type of authentication is used by `connect hr/password` ? Athentication by OS o by Password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only user having `sysdba` and `sysoper` privilege are connected to database using password file authentication. Other users such as `HR` are authenticated using data dictionary.

Password file is required for `SYSDBA` and `SYSOPER` privileged users to make remote connection. As I said earlier other users are authenticated using data dictionary, password file is not required for them to make remote connection.

The password is stored in encrypted form user undocumented table called `USER$`.

```
SQL> select password from user$ where name='HR';

PASSWORD
------------------------------
4FF80DF8D8DBE02E
```

Comment: Soooo sorry to ask questions again...Authenticated in the database means other users password is in the data dictionnary (which view) ? Does that mean that remote logging is not possible for users not owning `sysdba` nor `sysoper` ?

Comment: @user118627: See the update for the first part. Remote login is possible for all non-sys users because their password are stored in database.